# Oracle select query with inner select query error

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am getting a SQL error and trying to resolve, any pointers would be helpful,

// this gets executed

`SELECT empid  FROM employees WHERE deptid IN (10,20,30,40 );`

// this gets executed

```
SELECT deptid FROM department WHERE description LIKE '%application%' 
  ORDER BY createddate DESC
```

but the below query throws error:

```
SELECT empid  FROM employees WHERE deptid IN (SELECT deptid FROM department WHERE description LIKE '%application%' 
  ORDER BY createddate DESC);
```

error:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"

**Update: 07/14:**

Updating with the exact solution from @dasblinkenlight:

> The problem is placing ORDER BY in the WHERE clause subquery. SQL
>   syntax does not allow you to order elements of the subquery in the
>   WHERE clause, because it does not change the result of the query
>   overall

This article well explains many of the concepts - http://oraclequirks.blogspot.com/2008/01/ora-00907-missing-right-parenthesis.html

> "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis Clearly when one gets a message
>   like this, the first reaction is probably to verify what parenthesis
>   has been left out, but unfortunately there are no missing parentheses
>   at all in this statement.
>
> To cut it short, the untold syntax quirk is summarized as follows:
>   don't use ORDER BY inside an IN subquery.
>
> Now, one may object that indeed it doesn't make sense to use the ORDER
>   BY inside an IN clause, which is true, because Oracle doesn't care
>   about the row order inside an IN clause:"

I tried the SQL statement with WHERE clause and '=' instead of 'IN' and it still threw the error:'`missing right parenthesis`'.

**conclusion 1** :

"Don't use ORDER BY in the WHERE clause subquery"
 or "Subqueries in the where clause are not allowed to use ORDER BY in Oracle"

**Conclusion 2**

This case-study also shows the scenario where we should go for JOIN rather than select subquery

Comment: take a look at this article: http://oraclequirks.blogspot.com/2008/01/ora-00907-missing-right-parenthesis.html

Comment: wow, very good article, extra information , Thank you so much @beherenow

Comment: your conclusion 1 is not entirely correct. subqueries in where clause ARE allowed to use order by, BUT only in case where order by affects result set - for instance, where it provides top-n filtering, like in this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8. in other case it throws ora-907. you might also want to take a look at MOS article 731577.1, which I just found - they seem to have a lot of SRs about this so they clarified this )

Comment: beherenow, sure I will go through your fiddle and those articles and will either update my conclusion or clarify with you if I come across any queries.  Appreciate your effort to review my post even after it is marked as solved.  But this is the conclusion shared by both @dasblinkenlight and GordonLinoff

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is placing `ORDER BY` in the `WHERE` clause subquery. SQL syntax does not allow you to order elements of the subquery in the `WHERE` clause, because it does not change the result of the query overall.

You should move it out to fix the syntax:

```
SELECT empid  FROM employees WHERE deptid IN
    (
        SELECT deptid FROM department WHERE description LIKE '%application%'
    )
ORDER BY createddate DESC
```

> `createddate` is not a column in `employees` table. It exists only in `department` table

Then you need to join to the `department` table, and use `ORDER BY` on one of its columns:

```
SELECT e.empid
FROM employees e
JOIN department d ON e.deptid = d.deptid
WHERE d.description LIKE '%application%'
ORDER BY d.createddate DESC
```

Comment: Thank you for that explaining the root-cause. But moving it out is incorrect as `createddate` is not a column in `employees` table. It exists only in `department` table. Still I tried, and got the expected error of 'invalid identifier'

Comment: @prash Would you like to order employees on the creation date of the department then?

Comment: @prash Of course, you can't use identifier from subquery on the outer query. LAs I said, ordering your subquery will not buy you anything anyway

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff . I updated my post with the conclusion

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, you don't need `order by` in your subquery and you can remove it and then parenthesis will be just right

```
SELECT empid  
FROM employees 
WHERE deptid IN (SELECT deptid 
                 FROM department 
                 WHERE description LIKE '%application%');
```

If you want to apply `order by` you would have to do it on your outer query

Comment: Thank you for the answer and comments, +1. But since this doesnt address how to place the order by, I am accepting the other as my complete answer. Thank you, though

Comment: @prash No problem, I was also only concentrating on "why your query is not working" and didn't do anything on solving the issue in general. And I gave +1 to `dasblinkenlight` for thinking further