# Select top 10 salary from employees table

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote this sql query:

```
select first_name, salary 
from employees 
where salary in( select distinct top(10) salary from employees order by salary  disc );
```

When I ran it, I got this error:

SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"

What could have caused the error?

Comment: Is `disc` a column or an mispelling for `desc`? This might be the cause of your error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle select query with inner select query error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24746087/oracle-select-query-with-inner-select-query-error)

Comment: Try it without the order by clause in the sub-query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Top-N query is typically performed this way in Oracle:

```
select * from (
select first_name, salary 
from employees order by salary desc
) where rownum <= 10
```

This one gets you top 10 salaries.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem lies in the use of `top` which is SQL Server and not Oracle.

Use `rank` instead to get the salary in the decent order and get the first 10 of them:

```
select v.first_name, v.salary 
from ( select first_name, salary, rank() over (order by salary desc) r from employees) v
where v.r <= 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
SELECT first_name, salary 
(  select first_name, salary 
   from employees 
   order by salary Desc)
where rownum <= 10
```

Answer (score 0):

The below Query works in Oracle.

select * from (select * from emp order by sal desc) where rownum<=10;

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
select emp_id, salary from orders
order by salary desc limit 10;
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this ===
 SELECT first_name, salary FROM employees WHERE salary IN (SELECT salary FROM employees GROUP BY salary ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 10);

Comment: `LIMIT` is for MySQL and here's ORACLE.